Sort Pandas dataframe by Sub Total and count
I have a very large dataset called bin_df.
Using pandas and the following code I've assigned sub-total "Total" to each group:
        bin_df = df[df["category"].isin(model.BINARY_CATEGORY_VALUES)]

        bin_category_mime_type_count_df = (
            bin_df.groupby(["category", "mime_type"])["mime_type"]
            .count()
            .reset_index(name="Count")
        )

The output from bin_category_mime_type_count_df :
      category                   mime_type  Count
          1      application/x-executable     19
          1  application/x-pie-executable    395
          1       application/x-sharedlib      1
          2       application/x-sharedlib    755
          3       application/x-sharedlib      1
          6          application/x-object    129

Then:
        bin_category_total_count_df = (
            bin_category_mime_type_count_df.groupby(["category", "mime_type"])[
                "Count"
            ]
            .sum()
            .unstack()
        )

        bin_category_total_count_df = (
            bin_category_total_count_df.assign(
                Total=bin_category_total_count_df.sum(1)
            )
            .stack()
            .to_frame("Count")
        )

        bin_category_total_count_df["Count"] = (
            bin_category_total_count_df["Count"].astype("Int64").fillna(0)
        )

This produces the following (it is sorted by category by default):
                                        Count
 category mime_type
 1        application/x-executable         19
          application/x-pie-executable    395
          application/x-sharedlib           1
          Total                           415
 2        application/x-sharedlib         755
          Total                           755
 3        application/x-sharedlib           1
          Total                             1
 6        application/x-object            129
          Total                           129

I would like it to be sorted by "Total" and then within a category I would like it to be sorted by mime_type Count:
                                        Count
 category mime_type
 2        application/x-sharedlib         755
          Total                           755
 1        application/x-pie-executable    395
          application/x-executable         19
          application/x-sharedlib           1
          Total                           415
 6        application/x-object            129
          Total                           129
 3        application/x-sharedlib           1
          Total                             1

What kind of function should I look at to get the desired result?

Example Code
import pandas as pd
data = {'Count': {(1, 'application/x-executable'): 19, (1, 'application/x-pie-executable'): 395, (1, 'application/x-sharedlib'): 1, (1, 'Total'): 415, (2, 'application/x-sharedlib'): 755, (2, 'Total'): 755, (3, 'application/x-sharedlib'): 1, (3, 'Total'): 1, (6, 'application/x-object'): 129, (6, 'Total'): 129}}
df = pd.DataFrame(data).rename_axis(['category', 'mime_type'])

Code
out = df.sort_values(
    'Count', 
    ascending=False, 
    key=lambda x: list(
        zip(
            df.groupby(level=0)['Count'].transform(sum), 
            x.mask(df.index.get_level_values(1) == 'Total', -1)
        )
    )
)

out


Assuming bin_category_mime_type_count_df as input, I would rethink the way you compute the totals (the unstacked intermediate is not efficient). Rather perform a single groupby.sum and sort the total, then use this information to reorder the categories (with sort_values+Categorical) after a concat step to combine the counts and total values:
# get the sum per group
# sort the categories by total
tmp = (
    bin_category_total_count_df.groupby('category')[['Count']]
    .sum()
    .sort_values(by='Count', ascending=False)
    .assign(mime_type='Total').reset_index()
)

# combine the counts and Total
# sort by category
out = (pd.concat([bin_category_mime_type_count_df, tmp])
         .sort_values(by='category', kind='stable',
                      key=lambda x: pd.Categorical(x, categories=tmp['category'],
                                                   ordered=True),
                      ignore_index=True
                     )
      )

Variant for the second step:
out = (pd.concat([bin_category_mime_type_count_df, tmp])
         .astype({'category': pd.CategoricalDtype(categories=tmp['category'],
                                                  ordered=True)})
         .sort_values(by='category', kind='stable', ignore_index=True)
      )

Output:
   category                     mime_type  Count
0         2       application/x-sharedlib    755
1         2                         Total    755
2         1      application/x-executable     19
3         1  application/x-pie-executable    395
4         1       application/x-sharedlib      1
5         1                         Total    415
6         6          application/x-object    129
7         6                         Total    129
8         3       application/x-sharedlib      1
9         3                         Total      1

Intermediate tmp:
   category  Count mime_type
0         2    755     Total
1         1    415     Total
2         6    129     Total
3         3      1     Total


The subtotals should not be included in the final total, they were subtotals of the group. For example 1510 should be 755. Thanks for the sort_value , key argument example.

@Charlotte they are not, the code is working as expected. This was just a an error of mine when copying the outputs.
